# When Can Different Races Party Up?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

In Lord of the Rings Online, how far into the game do you need to get to create a fellowship with different races?  I see that dwarves and elves seem to start in a far different area than humans and hobbits.

I would like to make a new character who is a dwarf and play with friends who are planning to make humans and was wondering how long we would have to play seperate before we could team up and travel together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to finish the introductory instance which (if my memory serves me right) is around level 6. Once you leave the starter instance for whatever race you selected you should be able to swift travel at a stable to meet up with your friends. The Shire is a lot of fun if you are in to quest lore but from a strictly speed of leveling standpoint Breeland is much faster.

Comment: You can also skip the introductory instance, if you've done it before -- I don't recommend that, though, as it leaves you at level 1 in content designed for level 6.

Comment: You skip the instance, not the layered Archet/Combe/Thorin's Hall you get put in after that.

Comment: Ah, they used to let you skip the whole thing, back in the day.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info.  I played it last night with the guys.  We are all new to the game, and it's amazing how large the world is. (Especially since there doesn't really appear to be much in the way of fast travelling at the start!)